# Can't install any extension on WAMP64

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, magento-connect-manager, wamp

I'm spending 2 days on google to solve this problem(s), and tried many solutions without any success. Please help. :)

I'm new to Magento and using version 1.9.3.1 on WAMP 3.0.6(64bits).

Tried many extensions to install via Magento Connect but without any success. 
It keeps give me a message: "**Exception during cache and session cleaning**".

Also tryed to manualy download and copy/paste content in root folder, and then logout/login to admin panel to see changes and they are installed, but doesn't work becuse cache isn't cleaned i suppose. Here is the example of Advanced Code Editor extension.

[image: Advanced Code Editor]
I disabled caches in admin panel, as well(right after installing Magento), and go to **downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/Gz.php** and changed line of code from

```
$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen($this->_filePath, $mode);
```

to

```
$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen64($this->_filePath, $mode);
```

but then is even worse, because after try to install it extension it gave me an error on front end and backend page, and can't access it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Go to **downloader/Maged/Connect.php**, find

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.JSONeval(true) || {};
```

replace it with:

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || JSON.parse(transport.responseText) || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, if you want immediate solution. Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i didn't face any security problems.

Comment: Already try that and it's is same result, but i found solution. Read below. Btw you can direct download extension from Magento Connect by installing chrome extension as well.